ggplot stat_summary_bin Weighted Mean/Function with Argument
I would like to use ggplot's stat_summary_bin() function to make a binscatter where the output is a weighted mean.
I know how to make a plot without the weights, e.g.
dat <- data.frame(depVar = rnorm(100), expVar = rnorm(100), weightVar = runif(100))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = depVar, y = expVar)) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun = 'mean')

But I have not been able to change the function to a weighted mean and use the weight variable weightVar.

I have tried the fun.args argument to stat_summary_bin(), but have not been able to make it work. (I have not found much documentation on how it works, if this is the solution.)
Some other answers suggested I should introduce the weight through the aes mapping, but I am not sure if this is the ideal solution.

More generally, I am not sure on how to use any function similar to weighted.mean() in stat_summary_bin() with an argument different from the x and y variables given in aes.
Any help would be appreciated!
